# How to draw a grid on a shape made of curved lines?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am a new user of the Tikz package and I would like to draw the image below using this package for my Thesis.[image]

I think I can create the first grid (left) because the lines are straight, however how could I draw the second grid of the deformed bar? Is there any way to 'deform' the first one or creating a grid from the deformed lines? 
Also, regarding the 'zoomed' details: is there any 'automatic' way to draw it using Tikz (I mean like a real zoom of the figure)? Or should I create them separately? 
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Maybe you can describe it as a function and use pgfplots?

Comment: I think it would be great to use tikz coordinate transformation, i.e. define your own coordinate system that describes the curve. Section 13.2.5 of the [pgfmanual](ftp://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) describes this, and there are a few examples on the internet. but, however interested I am, I'm afarid I don't have time to try this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a bit fiddly getting the non-linear transformation stuff working in `pgf` but it can more-or-less do what is required along with the `spy` library:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5]{standalone}
\usepgfmodule{nonlineartransformations}
\usepgflibrary{curvilinear}
\usetikzlibrary{spy,calc}
\tikzset{pics/grid/.style={code={%
  \tikzset{x=10pt, y=10pt, step=10pt}
  \draw [thin] (-2, 0) grid ++(4, 20);
  \draw [thick] (-2, 0) rectangle ++(4, 20) (-4, 0) -- (4, 0);
  \draw [thick, fill=gray!50] (0,14) rectangle ++(1,1)
   ++(-.5,-.5) coordinate (-square);
  \draw [<->, thin, gray] (0,14) -- ++(1,1); 
  \coordinate (-corner) at (-2, 20);
}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,
  spy using outlines={circle, magnification=3, size=2.5cm, connect spies}]
\pic (a) {grid};
\draw [->, thick, shorten >=5] (a-corner) ++(-1,0)  -- (a-corner);
\spy [red] on (a-square) in node at ($(a-square)+(2.5,0)$);
\scoped{
  \pgfsetcurvilinearbeziercurve
    {\pgfpointxy{5}{0}}{\pgfpointxy{5}{10}}
    {\pgfpointxy{25}{15}}{\pgfpointxy{25}{20}}
  \pgftransformnonlinear{\pgfgetlastxy\x\y%
    \pgfpointcurvilinearbezierorthogonal{\y}{-\x}}%
  \pic (b) {grid};
}
\draw [->, thick, shorten >=5] (b-corner) ++(-1,0) -- (b-corner);
\spy [red] on (b-square) in node at ($(b-square)+(2.5,0)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks amazing. Do you compile with `pdflatex`? Right now the code freezes on me with an uninformative "Tikz gives up" error message. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Here's an attempt in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html).  It's wrapped up in `luamplib`, so compile with `lualatex`.

[image]

I've added the call outs in a second version below.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

    numeric u, x, y; 
    u = 5mm;
    x = 4;
    y = 17;
    path base;
    base = (left--right) scaled (2x*u);
    picture p[];

    p1 = image(
        path tower;
        tower = unitsquare shifted 1/2 left xscaled x yscaled y scaled u;

        path hh[], vv[];
        for i=1 upto x-1:
            vv[i] = point i/x of tower -- point 3-i/x of tower;
        endfor
        for i=1 upto y-1:
            hh[i] = point 1+i/y of tower -- point 4-i/y of tower;
        endfor

        path sq; sq = buildcycle(hh[14],vv[3],hh[15],vv[2]);
        fill sq withcolor 7/8[red,white];

        for i=1 upto x-1: draw vv[i]; endfor
        for i=1 upto y-1: draw hh[i]; endfor

        drawoptions(withpen pencircle scaled 1.2);
        drawarrow point 3 of tower shifted (-4u,0) -- point 3 of tower shifted (-3,0);
        draw tower;
        draw base ;
        drawoptions();
    );
    p2 = image(
        path tower;
        tower = subpath (4,3) of fullcircle scaled 40u shifted (22u,0)
             -- subpath (3,4) of fullcircle scaled 48u shifted (22u,0)
             -- cycle;

        path hh[], vv[];
        for i=1 upto x-1:
            vv[i] = interpath(i/x,subpath(3,2) of tower, subpath (0,1) of tower);
        endfor
        for i=1 upto y-1:
            hh[i] = point i/y of tower -- point 3-i/y of tower;
        endfor

        path sq; sq = buildcycle(hh[14],vv[3],hh[15],vv[2]);
        fill sq withcolor 7/8[red,white];

        for i=1 upto x-1: draw vv[i]; endfor
        for i=1 upto y-1: draw hh[i]; endfor

        drawoptions(withpen pencircle scaled 1.2);
        drawarrow point 2 of tower shifted (-4u,0) -- point 2 of tower shifted (-3,0);
        draw tower;
        draw base ;
        drawoptions();
    );

    draw p1 shifted (-10u,0);
    draw p2 shifted (+10u,0);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

### And now in close-up...

There's no built in "spy" or magnifying-glass function in Metapost, but you can clip pictures to arbitrary paths, so it's not hard to roll-your-own.  Like this:

[image: The twin towers with spy holes]

Here's the code for the second version of the drawing:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

    numeric u, x, y; 
    u = 5mm;
    x = 4;
    y = 17;
    path base, loupe[];
    base = (left--right) scaled (2x*u);
    picture p[];

    p1 = image(
        path tower;
        tower = unitsquare shifted 1/2 left xscaled x yscaled y scaled u;

        path hh[], vv[];
        for i=1 upto x-1:
            vv[i] = point i/x of tower -- point 3-i/x of tower;
        endfor
        for i=1 upto y-1:
            hh[i] = point 1+i/y of tower -- point 4-i/y of tower;
        endfor

        path sq; sq = buildcycle(hh[14],vv[3],hh[15],vv[2]);
        fill sq withcolor 7/8[red,white];

        for i=1 upto x-1: draw vv[i]; endfor
        for i=1 upto y-1: draw hh[i]; endfor

        begingroup; interim ahangle := 24; interim ahlength := 2;
        drawdblarrow point 0 of sq -- point 3 of sq withcolor 1/2 white;
        label("$\scriptscriptstyle d\xi$", center sq + (2,-3));
        endgroup;

        drawoptions(withpen pencircle scaled 1.2);
        drawarrow point 3 of tower shifted (-4u,0) -- point 3 of tower shifted (-3,0);
        draw tower;
        draw base ;
        drawoptions();
    );

    loupe1 := fullcircle scaled 2u shifted center sq;
    loupe3 := fullcircle scaled 4u shifted center sq shifted (6u,u);
    p3 := p1;  
    clip p3 to loupe1;
    p3 := p3 shifted -center loupe1 scaled 2 shifted center loupe3;

    p5 = image(
        draw p1; draw p3;
        drawoptions(withcolor red);
        draw loupe1; draw loupe3;
        draw center loupe1 -- center loupe3
          cutbefore loupe1  cutafter loupe3;
        drawoptions();
    );

    p2 = image(
        path tower;
        tower = subpath (4,3) of fullcircle scaled 40u shifted (22u,0)
             -- subpath (3,4) of fullcircle scaled 48u shifted (22u,0)
             -- cycle;

        path hh[], vv[];
        for i=1 upto x-1:
            vv[i] = interpath(i/x,subpath(3,2) of tower, subpath (0,1) of tower);
        endfor
        for i=1 upto y-1:
            hh[i] = point i/y of tower -- point 3-i/y of tower;
        endfor

        path sq; sq = buildcycle(hh[14],vv[3],hh[15],vv[2]);
        fill sq withcolor 7/8[red,white];

        for i=1 upto x-1: draw vv[i]; endfor
        for i=1 upto y-1: draw hh[i]; endfor

        begingroup; interim ahangle := 24; interim ahlength := 2;
        drawdblarrow point 0 of sq -- point 3 of sq withcolor 1/2 white;
        endgroup;

        drawoptions(withpen pencircle scaled 1.2);
        drawarrow point 2 of tower shifted (-4u,0) -- point 2 of tower shifted (-3,0);
        draw tower;
        draw base ;
        drawoptions();
    );
    loupe2 := fullcircle scaled 2u shifted center sq;
    loupe4 := fullcircle scaled 4u shifted center sq shifted (-8u,2u);
    p4 := p2;  
    clip p4 to loupe2;
    p4 := p4 shifted -center loupe2 scaled 2 shifted center loupe4;

    p6 = image(
        draw p2; draw p4;
        drawoptions(withcolor red);
        draw loupe2; draw loupe4;
        draw center loupe2 -- center loupe4
          cutbefore loupe2  cutafter loupe4;
        drawoptions();
    );

    draw p5 shifted (-10u,0);
    draw p6 shifted (+10u,0);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```